# the same acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

Assume that mass A and mass B are contacted each other and kept at rest, if someone exerts an external force, then A and B will always have the same acceleration? What about A and B are contacted by a massless ring?

Comment: It depends on whether the ring is deformable or not.

Answer (score 0):

In this case A and B would act like a single mass $M=m_A+m_B$ since they're bound together. This means given a force $F$ the acceleration obviously would be
$$a=\frac{F}{M}=\frac{F}{m_A+m_B}$$
for both the masses. Hope this answers your question :)

EDIT: I am assuming they're RIGIDLY bound together